# how does async.parallel work in nodejs with a single thread

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, event-loop

The async library in nodejs provides many methods like parallel and times to execute multiple calls in parallel. How can this be really parallel since nodejs is single threaded and the event loop can pick only one job at a time.

Does this mean async.parallel is not really parallel and only asynchronous ? I understand that both asynchronous and parallel are totally different terms.

Comment: You are right. It's `concurrent`, not `parallel`. Concurrcy can run on single thread and give significant performance which is what node.js does with event loop. Read - https://bytearcher.com/articles/parallel-vs-concurrent/

Comment: What `async.parallel` means by parallel is that it will put the jobs in queue for run one after the other and let them run as event loop decide. It's just a syntactic sugar for concurrent promises running together. `async.serial` for instance puts one job and waits for it to complete (done from it's event cycle) before putting the next one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the blog. So what I understand is async.parallel provides benefit only if it has asynchronous code inside. What is the difference between calling an asynchronous job inside loop and using async.parallel to execute the same job? I expect both to behave in the same way.

Comment: `async.parallel` will make sure that it accumulates the results in order of jobs and give you them in callback, also it provides the exceptional handler if any job fails - much like how promises work (and accumulate with `Promise.all`). Doing inside a loop will take away that flexibility and you will never be sure when the job completed or what happened to it.